# Can android PopupWindow show another PopupWindow?

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow

Can android PopupWindow show another PopupWindow?
How many PopupWindow can be opened in the same time? Only one?

The first PopupWindow is displayed normally. But on button click (which is in the first PopupWindow contentview) i am having an exception:

```
08-13 16:28:38.682: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41286250 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:600)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:313)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:992)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:901)
        at org.example.qberticus.quickactions.BetterPopupWindow.showLikePopDownMenu(BetterPopupWindow.java:159)
        at org.example.qberticus.quickactions.BetterPopupWindow.showLikePopDownMenu(BetterPopupWindow.java:129)
        at name.antonsmirnov.android.popup.ui.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4170)
        at name.antonsmirnov.android.popup.ui.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14157)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the code is:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bindControls();
    initControls();
}

private Button button;

private void bindControls() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

private void initControls() {
    initButton(button);
}

private void initButton(final Button button) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final BetterPopupWindow window = new BetterPopupWindow(button);

            View popupview = createPopupView();
            window.setContentView(popupview);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    window.showLikePopDownMenu();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private View createPopupView() {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.window, null);
    Button popupButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.popupbutton);
    initButton(popupButton);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After playing with it i've found that

```
    window.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER, x, y);
```

works okay, but

```
    window.showAsDropDown(getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER, x, y);
```

raises exception! If you use `showAtLocation(view)` with any view different from `getWindow().getDecorView()` you'll still have an exception.

Comment: thank you so much! This was holding me up for hours.
Btw. you will get the same error when placing a Spinner inside the popup and opening its dropdown menu.
I think this is a bug in the API.

Comment: How can I anchor the nested popup window to the views in the popup window? Your solution solves the crash but it doesn't get anchored to the parent popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. but here after looking at the exception stack trace, it seems like you are giving  the wrong context. try to Launch another dialog with the same context or the context of your activity if that is not a child view of any parent such as TabView.

Comment: No, the context is ok and the first PopupWindow is shown. But the second PopupWindow that should be shown on button click from the first PopupWindow can't be shown.

Comment: OK. Can you just paste here what your are doing in click event? I mean your onClick() method of that button. It would be a great help to find the bug.

Comment: BetterPopupWindow is used from [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/source/browse/trunk/src/org/example/qberticus/quickactions/BetterPopupWindow.java?r=8)

Comment: I am not 100% sure but you can try this, instead of making instance with final BetterPopupWindow window = new BetterPopupWindow(button); you can use final BetterPopupWindow window = new BetterPopupWindow(getWindow().getDecorView());. If you are in activity class.

Comment: then PopupWindow is not shown at all. Tested on android 4.0.4