# Autocomplete TextView in PopupWindow

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am showing PopupWindow on button click like this.

```
public void Search_Click(View view) {
    try 
    {
      Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) IssueTokenActivity.this
                                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up_transporter_details,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
      AutoCompleteTextView act=(AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.act_trans_name);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
        dataadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        act.setAdapter(dataadapter);
        act.setThreshold(1);

        //TODO: Need to support for higher API
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,display.getWidth()-60, display.getHeight()-400, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error while typing in AutoCompleted TextView.

```
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@40ece840 is not valid; is your activity running?
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:993)
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:899)
06-20 09:15:47.091: E/AndroidRuntime(23277):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:603)
```

Comment: Don't inflate the layout file and add it to the `R.id.popup_element` ViewGroup and then add that inflated layout as the content for the `PopupWindow`.

Comment: Thanks,Can you give some more detail?

Comment: For start use `View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up_transporter_details,
                        null);` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: No still getting the same error

Comment: It seems that you can't show another `PopupWindow` from a `PopupWindow` and that is exactly what the `AutoCompleTextView` does. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932578/can-android-popupwindow-show-another-popupwindow

Comment: Did you find a way to fix the error I am facing the same problem?

Comment: No as far as i know there is noway to do this..As @Luksprog said we can't have popupwindow in another popupwindow.

Comment: Refer here [Autocomplete TextView in PopupWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303527/autocompletetextview-not-working-inside-popup-window/56680894#56680894)

Comment: I seemed to have same problem. Please refer here [autocompletetextview not working inside popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303527/autocompletetextview-not-working-inside-popup-window/56680894#56680894)

Answer (score 1):

Better to use dialog(android.app.Dialog) to implement AutoCompleteTextView.In my opinion its not possible to add  AutoCompleteTextView in PopupWindow(you will get Exception).You can add Spinner in Popupwindow.You can implement both if are using dialog instead of popup.